# Ways in using a struct to get and set a value?

Tags: swift, struct

The problem I'm having with structs is trying to get and set values.
I try to store my ivars as such:

> let origin.x = 10, origin.y = 10

However, I'm confused as to how to utilize the getter and setters. I have an origin, but what should I put into my **newCenter** parameter?

```
struct Point {
var x = 0.0, y = 0.0

}

struct Rect {
     var origin = Point(x: 10, y: 10)
     var size = Size()
     var center: Point {
         get {
            let centerX = origin.x + (size.width / 2)
            let centerY = origin.y + (size.height / 2)
            return Point(x: centerX, y: centerY)
         }
         set(newCenter) {
            origin.x = newCenter.x - (size.width / 2)
            origin.y = newCenter.y - (size.height / 2)
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be mostly correct - nothing need to be "put into" the `newCenter` parameter. However, you are incorrectly dividing by `size.width` instead of `size.height` when calculating the y position.

When you use `foo.center = bar`, `bar` will be the value of `newCenter`.